# Удаляется ли localHistory после установления флага localHistory.dayToKeep = 0?

Tags: intellij-idea

Поставил в настройках количество дней хранения LH = 0. LH перестала отображаться. Если я передам свой проект на другой компьютер, где значение != 0, то она будет видна? Если это так, то как ее можно удалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Для более полной информации [СЮДА](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867429/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-intellij-idea/867440#867440).**

Да, удаляется.

Я поменял значение обратно на `5`. После этого у меня не появилась история которая была несколько дней назад. Я провел несколько изменений, и история этих изменений стала видна.

P.S. Делается это так: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `/` -> `Registry` -> ищем флаги.