# Где храниться история в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

И как ее удалить? И если я закоммичу проект, то история попадет на GitHub?

Comment: история хранится в git (скорее всего). И это скорее всего будет папка .git  в рабочем каталоге. На гитхаб оно попадет, если проект "запушить". Если сильно хочется "удалить" - ну так удалите каталог .git, правда после этого и сам репозиторий пропадет.

Comment: @KoVadim не та, которая в git, а та которая есть и до подключения гита, во вкладке VCS -> Show local history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalHistory в IntelliJ IDEA храниться в `.idea/workspace`.
История GitHub храниться в скрытой папке `.git` в рабочем каталоге(т.е. там где ваш проект).